# Select all replies to a post and its updates

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table (MySQL) with some posts for each category that "receive" a bunch of comments. If you select the wrong category, me as administrator can change it so i created a table as a kind of "update log".

Now I want to select a post's comments and its updates (something like "Your post was changed to Category Something_1").

The tables are:

```
POSTS: id | title | message | status | id_user | id_category | date

POSTS_COMMENTS: id | id_post | comment_text | date

POSTS_CHANGE_LOG: id | id_post | changed_to | date
```

Can you help me?

Comment: So, given some sample data, what exactly would you want the resulting dataset to look like?

Comment: What did you try already to solve this problem?

Comment: I assume, you want this to be a single query, right?

Comment: If you want all comments and all changes, just run two queries.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a code writing service. You have to learn the basics of e.g. sql and ask spexific questions then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the post can only be changed once (i.e. you have some constraints on POST_CHANGE table), you can use the following query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.id_category as "Original category", IFNULL(pcl.changed_to, p.id_category) as "New Category", pc.id as comment_id, pc.comment_text, pc.date
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN posts_change_log pcl ON p.id = pcl.id_post
JOIN posts_comments pc ON p.id = pc.id_post
WHERE p.id = ?
```

If a post can be changed multiple times then it's better to return/show post history and comments in separate queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.id, p.id_category as "Original category", pc.changed_to as "New Category"
FROM post p JOIN posts_change_log pcl
ON p.id = pcl.id_post
WHERE p.id = ?


SELECT *
FROM posts_comments 
WHERE id_post = ?
```

**Update**

To combine both the outputs, you can use `UNION ALL` operator, e.g.:

```
SELECT comment_text, date, "comment" as "type
FROM posts_comments
WHERE id_post = ?

UNION

SELECT changed_to, date, "change" as "type"
FROM post_change_log
WHERE id_post = ?

ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: It can be change multiple times... But i also wanted to order both Comments and Change_log by date.

Like this:
Comment 1
-------------------------------
Changed to category_2
-------------------------------
Comment 2

Comment: You can use `ORDER BY` in the above queries order the records. If you can have multiple updates then the `JOIN` will return MxN records where M is number of updates and N is number of comments. Could you post an example of exected output?

Comment: The output i want is exactly like this:
https://imageshack.us/i/poQC4fttp

Comment: @PauloGuedes I have added another query, could you try that?

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much, for yor help!! ;-)